# Minimal surface on $R^3$ with with non Euclidean metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde, minimal-surfaces

I am wondering if there is an analog of the following theorem by Morgan and White:
Suppose $g_E$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbf R^3$. If $\gamma$ is a closed $C^{k,\alpha}$ curve in $(\mathbf R^3,g_E)$ that bounds a unique area minimizing surface, then every closed curve sufficiently closed to $\gamma$ in $C^{k,\alpha}$ also bounds a unique area minimizing surface.

Specifically, I am wondering what happens if we fix a curve, say a circle in $\mathbf R^3$, and let the metric change. Intuitively, when the metric is closed to $g_E$, one expects that $\gamma$ still bounds a unique minimal surface. Is there any theorem that settled this question? More generally, if I consider the set of all circles on $\mathbf R^3$, do I expect that when the metric $g$ is closed to $g_E$, all of them bound a unique area minimizing surface?

Any insight or reference would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a reference for this "theorem"? I do not think it is true in general. The point is that if the area-minimizer bounded by $\gamma$ has a non-trivial Jacobi field (with Dirichlet boundary conditions) then it is possible to bifurcate two area-minimizers as you perturb.

Comment: This is analogous to the situation for geodesics in a manifold: If $q\in \textrm{Cut}(p)$ but there's a unique minimizing geodesic from $p$ to $q$ then there's a normal Jacobi field on the geodesic vanishing at the endpoints. In some situations this means that when $q$ is perturbed (within the cut locus) then there are two minimizing geodesics. This can happen on the paraboloid (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1663734)

Comment: On the other hand, since the disk in $R^3$ is strictly stable, the second part of your question is true (if you perturb $g_E$ to $g$) then there's still a unique minimizer). (I can add a proof if you want).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. You are right, I forgot the crucial condition is that the area-minimizing surface bounded by $\gamma$ has no non-trivial Jacobi field. The theorem I was talking about is theorem 3 in here: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-01/S0002-9947-1984-0735418-6/.

Comment: Regarding the second question, I would love to see your argument on it. I think that the neighborhood of $g_E$ that guarantees the uniqueness of the area-minimizer depends on each $\gamma$ (in my case, circle). My second question here is that is there such a uniform neighborhood that works for all circles?

Comment: Naruto: Are you using the word "surface" to mean specifically an embedded (or immersed) surface? Or something else?

Comment: Daniel Asimov: I mean surfaces in most general sense (allowing singularity). However, I would be mostly interested in the set of "nice enough" curves, and so all area-minimizer will be smooth embedded disks.

Comment: If a smoothly embedded circle is unknotted but remains close enough to a double-covering of the unit circle in the xy-plane, then the unique area minimizer could be a smoothly embedded Möbius band, not a disk.

Comment: Naruto: There is no standard definition of "surfaces in the most general sense". It is necessary to specify exactly what kind of surfaces you are talking about. That means what differentiability you are assuming, if any, and whether your surfaces are embedded, immersed, or just mapped in with no conditions about injectivity or local injectivity. (I presume from your comment that they are just mapped in, but that doesn't specify the differentiability class.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I sketch the proof of the following theorem:

> Theorem: Suppose that $\Sigma^n\subset (M^{n+1},g_0)$ is smooth and uniquely area-minimizing relative to it's boundary $\Gamma : = \partial\Sigma$ and is strictly stable (no nontrivial Jacobi fields with Dirichlet boundary conditions). Then if $g$ is a sufficiently small $C^{k,\alpha}$ perturbation of $g_0$, there's a unique area minimizer with boundary $\Gamma$ for the metric $g$ (and it's still smooth and strictly stable).

---

Remarks:

1. I think $k =1, \alpha \in (0,1)$ should suffice but I didn't think through each step very carefully to verify this.)
2. Note that this theorem actually proves the Euclidean one since if $\gamma,\gamma'$ are nearby boundaries, then you can find $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ diffeomorphism (small) taking $\gamma'$ to $\gamma$. Then the $\gamma'$ solution (for $g_E$) is a $\gamma$ solution for $\Phi^*g_E$.

---

Proof: Suppose that $g\to g_0$ and $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ are distinct $g$-minimizers with boundary $\Gamma$ (singular is fine). Since $\Sigma$ is smooth then Allard's theorem (interior and boundary) imply that $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ converge smoothly to $\Sigma$ all the way up to the boundary. In other words, there's $u_1,u_2$ on $\Sigma$ so that $\textrm{graph}(u_i) = \Sigma_i$ and $u_i |_{\partial\Sigma} = 0$ (where the graph is taken using the normal exponential map of $g_0$) and $u_i\to 0$ in some $C^{k',\alpha}$ space (which you have to work out depending on $k$). Write $H(u,g)$ for the mean curvature of the graph (as above) of $u$ with respect to $g$. Note that $H(u_i,g) = 0$ by assumption. Thus,
$$
0 = H(u_2,g)-H(u_1,g) = D_1H(u_1,g) (u_2-u_1) + O(||u_2-u_1||_{C^2}^2)
$$
(we used Taylor's theorem). The error is uniform with respect to the metric.

Now, divide by $||u_2-u_1||_{C^2}$ to get that $w:=(u_2-u_1)/||u_2-u_1||_{C^2}$ satisfies
$$
0 = D_1H(u_1,g) w + o(1)
$$
Using Schauder estimates we can get that $||w||_{C^{2,\alpha}} = O(1)$ (you have to check that the $o(1)$ term is bounded in $C^\alpha$ and that $D_1(u_1,g)w$ is a uniformly elliptic operator. Note that as $g\to g_0$ and $u_1\to 0$, $D_1H(u_1,g)$ limits to the Jacobi operator on $\Sigma$ with respect to $g_0$ (this is the definition of the Jacobi operator $J=D_1H(0,g_0)$. Moreover, by the $C^{2,\alpha}$ bounds for $w$, we get that the limit $w_0$ is $C^2$ and nonzero and solves $Jw_0 = 0$ (with Dirichlet boundary conditions).

This is a contradiction, proving uniqueness for $g$ minimizers, $g$ close to $g_0$. Strict stability follows from the fact that the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of $J$ is continuous as the metric and minimizer varies.

---

For your second question about the result being uniform for all disks,  this cannot be true. Here is a strange proof (probably there is a simpler way):

Construct a non-flat $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ rotationally symmetric with scalar curvature $> 0$ and so that $g=g_E + O(r^{-1})$ at infinity (along with derivatives). This is called an asymptotically flat metric. It turns out that you can do this with $||g-g_E||_{C^k}$ as small as you like. (You can also do this while arranging that there are no closed minimal surfaces in $(\mathbb{R}^3,g)$). This can all be accomplished by looking at the scalar curvature of $dr^2 + \varphi(r)^2 g_{S^2}$ and playing around with the resulting differential inequality.)

Thus, it suffices to prove that for this metric $g$ fixed, for $R$ sufficiently large, the circle of radius $R$ in the $xy$-plane has non-unique minimizers. Suppose the minimizer was unique. Then, by symmetry it must be the disk in the $xy$-plane. (The symmetry of the manifold already shows this is a minimal surface, but it might not be the minimizer; if not the minimizer then $z\mapsto -z$ takes the minimizer to a second one!).

If each disk of radius $R$ was a minimizer then the $xy$-plane will be a minimizer (on compact sets). However, the [proof](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0526976) of the positive mass theorem  shows that the scalar curvature would vanish along the plane. (Alternatively, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.07406.pdf) and the references contained within.)

---

For your question in the comment, I think the following is true:

> Theorem: Fix $R_0>0$ and suppose that $||g-g_E||_{C^{k,\alpha}} \leq \epsilon=\epsilon(R_0)$. Then there's a unique $g$-minimizer for any circle of radius $R\leq R_0$.

Proof: If not there's $g\to g_E$ in $C^{k,\alpha}$ and circles $C$ with radius $R\leq R_0$ where things fail. You can translate $C$ to the origin and rescale so that they have radius $1$. The rescaled metrics $g'$ still converge in $C^{k,\alpha}$ (this is where we used $R\leq R_0$). Thus, the previous proof applies.

Comment: Hi Otis. Thank you so much for the detailed answer. The counter example for circle of large radius make perfect sense to me. I am wondering now if we only restrict to the set of circles with bounded radii, would the result be true?